# Thymeleaf with a single bean as context instead of variables map?

Tags: thymeleaf

For a little side project I dabble with Thymeleaf (have mostly used Freemarker in the past).

I like to have all my template variables bundled nicely together in a single Java Bean (Kotlin data class, actually).

However, to create a Context for the template engine to process, I need to supply a `Map<String, Object>`. Why is that?

Currently, one option would be to create the context as `Map.of("model", myBean)` and use that "model" prefix everywhere in my template like `${model.userName}`.

Another option would be to "unpack" the Bean into a map of root properties manually or via reflection.

Both feel ways feel silly and unnecessarily complicated, especially because Thymeleaf already includes OGNL and should easily be able to determine the root properties of a bean itself, right?

Is there a better way to set a single bean instance as the root for variable evaluation?